# Calculate the new coordinates of a Vector3 array if the first point's coordinates changes

Tags: vector-spaces

let's say we have this line which is an array of Vector3, the first element of the array has the coordinates (1,0,5), like in the picture

[image]

let's say i want to move the first point of the array to (-10,5,-3), how can i calculate the other points new coordinates to get the same line like in this picture ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a translation. Note that you are subtracting $11$ from the first coordinate, adding $5$ to the second, and subtracting $8$ from the third. Repeating this with all points in the array will yield the translated array. In vector notation, if $\vec{a} = (-10, 5, -3) - (1, 0, 5)$, then translating the array involves adding $\vec{a}$ to all elements of the array.

Answer (score 2):

For each $(x,y,z)$ coordinate for each point, move it like the following

$$
(x,y,z) \Rightarrow (x-11,y+5,z-8)
$$

Essentially you are shifting them by the same amount as the first point is shifted.